# Sharepoint document library

Tags: sharepoint

We have one document library with 20 folders and more than 800 documents.
According to requirement we need to add  some extra columns to the existing document library.
my Questions are
1) After adding columns what value will gets stored for each document's those columns in doc library.
2) Can I update only those columns for each document in the library.

Comment: You should ask one question at a time.  It makes it easier to answer them, easier for others to find a relevant solution and gives appropriate credit for those who do answer.

Answer (score 0):

1)  It depends on what types of column you are using - a bit more info?

2)  Create a "flat" view containing your new columns: (Edit the view within the document library, within the "Folders" section of the edit view page you can select "Show all items without folders").  Open the view in data sheet view.  You can then bulk edit the columns.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. one doubt here is what is flat view? and columns are like Client Name,Project Name etc single line of text.